# Pandas : How to drop a specific number of duplicates rows?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, rows, drop

I hope you're doing well.
So I want to drop a specific number of duplicates rows. Let me explain by an example :

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 2   3
1   foo nan 9
2   foo 1   4
3   bar 8   nan
4   xxx 9   10
5   xxx 4   4
6   xxx 9   6
```

So we have duplicated rows based on column A, so for 'foo' I want to drop 2 duplicates rows for example and for 'xxx' I want to drop just one row.
The method drop_duplicates can keep either 0 or 1 rows so it didn't help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know how many rows to drop?

Comment: I have for example a dictionary nb_drops = {'foo':2, 'xxx':1}

Comment: @AbdelfattahBoutanes your comment above is a vital info which is missing from the question. I suggest you add it in the body of the question. Until then the question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the optimal solution, but this one works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo','foo','foo','bar','xxx','xxx','xxx'],
    'B': [2,np.nan,1,8,9,4,9],
    'C': [3,9,4,np.nan,10,4,6]
})
nb_drops = {'foo':2, 'xxx':1}
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for k, v in nb_drops.items():
  df2 = df2.append(df[df['A'] == k].head(v))
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A'])
df = df.merge(df2,how='outer')
df
```

Gives

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 2.0 3.0
1   bar 8.0 NaN
2   xxx 9.0 10.0
3   foo NaN 9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this code and it works...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo','foo','foo','bar','xxx','xxx','xxx'],
    'B': [2,np.nan,1,8,9,4,9],
    'C': [3,9,4,np.nan,10,4,6]

nb_drops = {'foo':2, 'xxx':1}
rows_to_delete = []
for item in nb_drops :
    indices_item = list(df[df['A'] == item].index)
    rows_to_delete += range(indices_item[-1] - nb_drops[item] + 1,indices_item[-1] + 1)

df.drop(rows_to_delete, inplace = True)
```